# progressview to represent the playback-iphone

Tags: iphone, uiprogressview

I have created an application which plays music files ia avaudioplayer. I need to show a progressview in the view to represent the play back of the song. Start from zero and end at the end of the song. How to implement that??? pls help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to another great forum.
It's not as easy as you think by the way. I suggest you start learning how to develop for the iPhone from the start.
Just bite the bullet and start!

Here's a link, read it and learn something:

http://bit.ly/8oCKNm

I suggest reading about `NSTimer` and `UIActivityIndicator`.
Have a nice day,
~ Natanavra.